# "PKWARE" compression format?

Tags: actionscript-3, compression, zip

On [this page](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=BLB#Decompression_of_PKWARE-compressed_Files), it mentions "PKWARE-compressed files". I know that PKWARE developed the ZIP format (among others), but apart from the DLL mentioned on the page I can't manage to find any documentation on a compression format specifically named "PKWARE". Is it just ZIP, is it an old compression that's no longer used, or something else?

I'm working with ActionScript 3.0, so either a specification on the format or an AS3 library would be sufficient. Does anybody know where I can get one of these two, or know anything helpful about the format?

Comment: I administer the wiki where you found that format description (www.multimedia.cx). I assume you're trying to work with BLB files? The format may very well be zlib-compatible (in which case, you would really be in luck since AS3 has native APIs for decompressing zlib data). Regrettably, we don't have any samples on record. Would you be able to share some for the collection? We might be able to lend assistance. My email is in my profile.

Comment: @MultimediaMike: Thanks, yeah I am trying to open BLB files. My internet just turned shoddy today so unfortunately I can't email you any files, but I will do so as soon as I can. In any case thanks for your assistance, it would be awesome if you could help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it says that they supply the PKWARE.DLL with their plug-in.  Have you tried using the DLL per the documentation that you linked to?

If you can provide an example, say the first 100 bytes of compressed data, then I can probably tell what it is.  It might be deflate, or it might be the weird PKWARE Data Compression Library, whose format is incompatible with deflate.

*Update:*

The provided first 100 bytes is DCL compressed data.  You can use the code in the [contrib/blast directory](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/contrib/blast) of the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) distribution to decompress it.  Or, of course, the PKWare DCL DLL.  It is not deflate.

Comment: Using a DLL from Actionscript is pretty difficult :)

Comment: As Vesper said, I'm using ActionScript hence I can't use the DLL. You may be right about the PKWARE DCL though. I'll see if I can extract the first 100 bytes for you, if you're still up for trying to find out the format that way.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I've extracted the first 100 bytes of a compressed graphics file. I've given it the extension .bin just to have an extension, but as you know it doesn't mean anything. Anyway here's a link: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/g2ivivqi7rc8m8f/100bytes.bin

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your update until now. Hopefully this should help me, if I manage to decompress the files successfully I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I was able to decompress the files just by running it through that sample blast.c app.

Comment: Whoops, totally late with this. Accepted your answer as it has helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[PKZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP) is very much in the mainstream. It's just that, due to lawsuits & patent issues it got a fork as zip.

You can follow about it at their [official site](http://www.pkware.com/software/pkzip) itself.

As for the format specification, [here](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip-printable.html) is a nice one describing the structure of PKZIP.

Hopefully, you can work your way up with structure in Action Script.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It could be the PKWARE Data Compression Library format.  Also what you linked is a description of the zip format.  Not a description of any compressed data format, like deflate.

Comment: By the way, what does "it got a fork as zip" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The normative documentation for PKZIP format is here: http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT .

Comment: A better description of the deflate compressed data format is RFC 1951, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1951 .  The information on the zip wrapper format is not useful here.

Comment: @MarkAdler Indeed, and there are many other compression formats besides Deflate used in ZIP. If we talk about *format* rather than algorithm, then Appnote applies.

Comment: I know of no DLL that would handle anything but deflate or DCL.  So it is very likely one of those.  Waiting on the first 100 bytes ...